# support for arch / arch_only flags in different (macports) gcc versions

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-snow-leopard, x86-64, macports

I'm on OSX snow leopard and using macports for newer versions of gcc.

What is the meaning of the -arch_only compiler flag for gcc? I'm confused as to what it does (I'm aware that "-arch x86_64" makes a 64 bit binary, but that's about it), and why support for it seems to vary between gcc versions.

macports gcc 4.4 supports it, macports 4.6-4.8 don't and give this error:

```
gcc-mp-4.8: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch_only'
```

Related to this, support for '-arch' seems to vary between versions too. 4.4 supports it, 4.6 doesn't, 4.7 and 4.8 do.

Comment: I'm running in the same problem when trying to compile _readline_. I came to [this link](http://techdebug.com/blog/2009/01/03/compiling-readline-on-an-osx-105-intel-x86_64), that may answer your question.